# not able to use array map function in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, array-map

array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Search' does not have a method 'wishList'

```
 $shops = array_map(array($this, 'wishList'), $shops);

 function wishList($shops) {
        print_r(shops);
        $this->check_authentication(); 
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $shops->isWishList = $this->Wishlist_model->_isShopInMyWishList($shops->id, $user->id,6) ? true : false;
        return $shops;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see that's the issue, you just declared your `wishList` function not in the `Search` class, if you wanna do this your should write this:

```
$shops = array_map('wishList', $shops);
```

Or move you `wishList` function to your `Search` class